# Razor to render news and category, Multiple models

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I m creating a news page. I have News Model and News have a Category. Category is coming from database. I want to be able to create News and assign category to the news. Below is how I tried to do it. Problem is I m trying to create a drop down for categories and once form is filled it ll be submitted to be saved in the database.

Here is the error: I m passing `IEnumerable<SelectListItem> categoriesList` to view but it s expecting News Model. How can I use multiple models in one view? how can i fix below code so it would work?

```
@model App.Models.News

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create news</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    <div>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Category Information</legend>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Title)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Title)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Title)
            </div> 

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Category)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Category)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Category)
            </div> 

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.NewsContent)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.NewsContent)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.NewsContent)
            </div> 
            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Log On" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
}

        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            IList<Category> categories;
            using (var session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
            {
                using (var tx = session.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    categories = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Category)).List<Category>();
                    tx.Commit();
                }

            }

            IEnumerable<SelectListItem> categoriesList = categories.Select(category => new SelectListItem() { Text = category.Name, Value = category.Id.ToString() });

            return View(categoriesList);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your view expects a News object you must pass a News object to it. And if you wanted to work with multiple models you could create a view model:

```
public class NewsViewModel
{
    public string SelectedCategoryId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Categories { get; set; }

    ... put any properties that your view might require
}
```

and then strongly type your view to `NewsViewModel` and have your controller action pass an instance of it to the view.

You should pass a News instance to your view:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    IList<Category> categories;
    using (var session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
    using (var tx = session.BeginTransaction())
    {
        categories = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Category)).List<Category>();
        tx.Commit();
    }
    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> categoriesList = categories.Select(category => new SelectListItem() { Text = category.Name, Value = category.Id.ToString() });
    var news = new NewsViewModel
    {
        Categories = categoriesList
    };
    return View(news);
}
```

and in your view:

```
@model App.Models.NewsViewModel
```

---

Another possibility (which I do not recommend) is to use `ViewBag`:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    IList<Category> categories;
    using (var session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
    using (var tx = session.BeginTransaction())
    {
        categories = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Category)).List<Category>();
        tx.Commit();
    }
    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> categoriesList = categories.Select(category => new SelectListItem() { Text = category.Name, Value = category.Id.ToString() });
    ViewBag.Categories = categoriesList;

    // or fetch from DB or whatever
    var news = new News();
    return View(news);
}
```

and in the view:

```
@model App.Models.News

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create news</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    <div>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Category Information</legend>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Title)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Title)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Title)
            </div> 

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Category)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Category)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Category)
            </div> 

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.NewsContent)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.NewsContent)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.NewsContent)
            </div> 

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.Label("SelectedCatgoryId")
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.DropDownList("SelectedCatgoryId", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Categories)
                @Html.ValidationMessage("SelectedCatgoryId")
            </div> 

            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Log On" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just have to create a wrapper model class for your two models:

```
public class Wrapper
{
    public App.Models.News News { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CategoriesSelectList { get; set; }
}
```

Then just update the references in your View.

Answer (score 1):

Create a ViewModel - a new Model containing both News and Categories

```
public class MyViewModel {
   public NewsType News { get; set; }
   public IEnumerable<CategoriesType> Categories { get;set; }
}
```

and use that model in your view.